# Target a div using form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a JSP page having a div which contains a form. On submit of the form the action goes to spring controller and return a new page I have to load the new page in the same div which called the action.

I can use only JavaScript.

Comment: Only *one* of your 12 other questions has received an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form, on form submit event page will go to location of form's action. To avoid it use a form with an Iframe. And onload of iframe you should set it's inner html as your target's inner html. Let me explain with a simple

```
<form action="url.php" id="formid" type="post" target="iframename">
    <input type="submit" onclick="submitFn()"/>
</form>
<irame id="iframeid" name="iframename" onload="onLoadFn()"></iframe>



/* Dont forget to hide your iframe */
iframe {
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border: none;
}


// This function will validate form and post it to form's action
function submitFn(){
    // validate form here
    document.getElementById('formid').submit()
}



// this function will handle form's post callback and load response to div
function onLoadFn(){
    document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('iframeid').innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible using "ordinary" code.

One way (that I personally dislike) is using inner frame, other way is using AJAX: instead of submitting the form, send AJAX request to the server with the same data and populate the `div` with the response from the server. Using jQuery it's matter of couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is little bit tricky to place iframe and div.

Here is the proper solution

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
    <script>
       function onLoadFn(){
            var frame = document.getElementById('resultFrame');
            if(frame){
               document.getElementById("targetDiv").innerHTML = (frame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML)
            }
        }
    </script>
<iframe name="resultFrame" id="resultFrame" width="100%" style="border:none;display:none" onload="onLoadFn()"></iframe>
```